# Integration by counting measure over 0,1-function

Tags: measure-theory

I'm really insecure about integrating $$ \int f(x,y) \, d \mu_1(x),  $$ where $\mu_1 $ is the counting measure on $\big([0,1], \mathcal P([0,1])\big)$ and $f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1,  & \text{if $x=y$ } \\
0, & \text{else} \end{cases}.$
As I read in the forum, integrating over the counting measure equals summation, so would I end up with $1 $ if $x=y$ and $0$ else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is nothing but $\int I_A d\mu_1$ where $A=\{x: x=y\}$. So the answer is $\mu_1 (A)=1$.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.